# groupby and remove pair records in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this,

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
a1      b1      c1      +
a1      b1      c1      +
a1      b2      c2      +
a1      b2      c2      -
a1      b2      c2      +
```

If there two records with identical values in `col1`,`col2` and `col3` and opposite sign in `col4`, they should be removed from dataframe.

Output:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
a1      b1      c1      +
a1      b1      c1      +
a1      b2      c2      +
```

So far I tried pandas `duplicated` and `groupby` but didn't succeeded with finding pairs. How to do this ?

Comment: In case of pairs (+, -), do you want to always keep "+", "-" or you don't care?

Comment: @Guybrush - It can be any string for replacement of +,-

Comment: You edited your question, and now I'm confused: what do you want to do exactly? Remove a row (a,b,c,d) if there exists (a,b,c,-)?

Comment: @Guybrush - If there two records with identical values in col1,col2 and col3 and opposite sign in col4, they should be removed from dataframe

Comment: Are the negative signs always preceded and followed by a +.  What if you have (+---+++)  Do you want remove all pairs leave (+) or just remove those - next to a positive leaving (-++)?  I think you need a more extensive testing set and expected outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for count groups define all `4` columns and then groupby again with helper `Series` define `+-` groups and compare with `set`:

```
s = df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3', 'col4']).cumcount()
df = df[~df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3', s])['col4']
           .transform(lambda x: set(x) == set(['+','-']))]
print (df)
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0   a1   b1   c1    +
1   a1   b1   c1    +
6   a1   b2   c2    +
```

For better understanding create new column:

```
df['help'] = df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3', 'col4']).cumcount()
print (df)
  col1 col2 col3 col4  help
0   a1   b1   c1    +     0
1   a1   b1   c1    +     1
2   a1   b2   c2    +     0
3   a1   b2   c2    -     0
4   a1   b2   c2    +     1

df = df[~df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3', 'help'])['col4']
           .transform(lambda x: set(x) == set(['+','-']))]
print (df)
  col1 col2 col3 col4  help
0   a1   b1   c1    +     0
1   a1   b1   c1    +     1
4   a1   b2   c2    +     1
```

Comment: I want to find duplicates in col1,col2,col3 only after that i need to remove records if pairs found. My expected output is not same in your answer

Comment: @MohamedThasinah - So for each group need remove `+/-` pairs?

Comment: yes If +/- pair found remove it. or else keep it same. for example if + symbol contains 5 times and - symbol contains 4 times in one group then 4 pairs should be removed and one + symbol should remain the same

Comment: @MohamedThasinah - you are right, answer was changed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt:

```
df[df.assign(ident=df.assign(count=df.col4.eq('+').astype(int))\
  .groupby(['col1','col2','col3','count']).cumcount())\
  .groupby(['col1','col2','col3','ident']).transform(lambda x: len(x) < 2)['col4']]
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0   a1   b1   c1    +
1   a1   b1   c1    +
4   a1   b2   c2    +
```

On a more robust test set:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['a1', 'b1', 'c1', '+'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', '+'], ['a1', 'b2', 'c2', '+'], ['a1', 'b2', 'c2', '-'], ['a1', 'b2', 'c2', '+'],
     ['a1','b3','c3','+'],['a1','b3','c3','-'],['a1','b3','c3','-'],['a1','b3','c3','-'],['a1','b3','c3','+'],['a1','b3','c3','+'],['a1','b3','c3','+'],['a1','b3','c3','+']], 
    columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
)
```

Input dataframe:

```
   col1 col2 col3 col4
0    a1   b1   c1    +
1    a1   b1   c1    +
2    a1   b2   c2    +
3    a1   b2   c2    -
4    a1   b2   c2    +
5    a1   b3   c3    +
6    a1   b3   c3    -
7    a1   b3   c3    -
8    a1   b3   c3    -
9    a1   b3   c3    +
10   a1   b3   c3    +
11   a1   b3   c3    +
12   a1   b3   c3    +

df[df.assign(ident=df.assign(count=df.col4.eq('+').astype(int))\
  .groupby(['col1','col2','col3','count']).cumcount())\
  .groupby(['col1','col2','col3','ident']).transform(lambda x: len(x) < 2)['col4']]
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2 col3 col4
0    a1   b1   c1    +
1    a1   b1   c1    +
4    a1   b2   c2    +
11   a1   b3   c3    +
12   a1   b3   c3    +
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the comment saying that " If there two records with identical values in col1,col2 and col3 and opposite sign in col4, they should be removed from dataframe", then:

1) Identify and drop duplicates: `df.drop_duplicates()`

2) Group them by the three first columns: `df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])`

3) Only keep groups that are of size 1 (otherwise, it means we have both "+" and "-"): `.filter(lambda group: len(group) == 1)`

All in one:

`df.drop_duplicates().groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3']).filter(lambda g: len(g) == 1)`

Answer (score 0):

First, group dataframe by `col1`, `col2` and `col3`. Then, apply method, that will subtract group's rows with different signs in `col4`.

In this method, replace values of `col4`, `+` to 1 and `-` to -1. Then sum values in `col4`(let's call variable, that keeps that sum `signed_row_count`). There only 2 results that are possible, either `+` rows will dominate(positive sum value) or `-` rows will(negative sum value). So, you can return new dataframe, with, either `signed_row_count` number of rows with `+` sign in `col4` or `signed_row_count` number of rows with `-` sign in `col4`, depending on sign of the sum.

Here is code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['a1', 'b1', 'c1', '+'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', '+'], ['a1', 'b2', 'c2', '+'], ['a1', 'b2', 'c2', '-'], ['a1', 'b2', 'c2', '+']], 
    columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
)
print(df)
#   col1 col2 col3 col4
# 0   a1   b1   c1    +
# 1   a1   b1   c1    +
# 2   a1   b2   c2    +
# 3   a1   b2   c2    -
# 4   a1   b2   c2    +

def subtract_rows(df):
    signed_row_count = df['col4'].replace({'+': 1, '-': -1}).sum()

    if signed_row_count >= 0:
       result = pd.DataFrame([df.iloc[0][['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].tolist() + ['+']] * signed_row_count, columns=df.columns)
    else:
        result = pd.DataFrame([df.iloc[0][['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].tolist() + ['-']] * abs(signed_row_count), columns=df.columns)

    return result

reduced_df = (df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
                .apply(subtract_rows)
                .reset_index(drop=True))
print(reduced_df)
#   col1 col2 col3 col4
# 0   a1   b1   c1    +
# 1   a1   b1   c1    +
# 2   a1   b2   c2    +
```